# Strapi create cart on user creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, strapi

I am new to Strapi and really enjoy the headless CMS so far.
Following a tuto, I built a simple eCom-like website with node/express and next. When creating a user, I create and assign automatically a cart

```
// in the signup logic, once you created the newUser:
await new Cart({ user: newUser._id }).save();
```

I am trying to do the same with Strapi but can't find a way. I tried a callback like

```
before save
```

but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no access to the user ID that do the request in life cycle of Strapi.

Here is the related issue - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1443

Comment: Thanks Jim, I understand. I'll try to find another way to link a Cart with a user.

Comment: I answered your question on Spectrum.

Comment: thanks Jim! For future refs:

https://spectrum.chat/strapi/tips-tricks/how-to-use-the-beforecreate-and-beforesave-callbacks-on-the-user-model~56bd7032-dd4d-4c14-80de-ba49db6e8cd3